# How to set properly rules on Firestore to get information to send an email on Ionic 4?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

i have rules to read and write on documents on Firestore, I set a rule that let you do "get" if a boolean is true, but the problem is it doesnt work... The message of "firebase error permission denied" appears when i'm using "emailComposer", what should I do on this case? Thank you so much

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /objects/{object} {
        allow read, write;
        allow get: if iWantToGetDataToSendAnEmail == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you put some code ?

Comment: updated, thank for your interest

Comment: Try change `match /objects/{object}` to   `match /{allPaths=**}`

Comment: ok so its like without security as i can see, to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, "get" is not a rule for firebase. Instead you want to use "read" to limit the read access like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /objects/{object} {
    allow write;
    allow read: if iWantToGetDataToSendAnEmail == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i put my question code without allow get also, and it didnt work, it was giving me also the firebase denied permission...